# MySQL LEFT Join - outputting based on <> operator

Tags: mysql, operators, left-join

I have the following query:

```
SELECT t1.location AS Locations, COUNT( t1.location ) AS Total,
tab.Responses, tab.location AS tablocation
FROM  `trespondent_acme` t1
LEFT JOIN (

SELECT location, COUNT( location ) AS Responses
FROM  `trespondent_acme` 
WHERE completion_status
IN (
'Started',  'Complete'
)
GROUP BY location
)tab ON t1.location = tab.location
GROUP BY t1.location
```

This provides the output (almost) that I am looking for.  In essence, it counts how many people there are in the various Locations in the `respondent` table and then also counts how many of those have responses from the `results` table.

Where I am coming unstuck is that I only want to count those from the `results` table that have completed if their response to a question doesn't equal a value - the MySQL code I am using is this

```
WHERE q13 <> 'OPTION'
```

The problem I am facing is where to place this part of the query to get the result I need.  Q13 resides within the `results` table by the way.  The places I have tried are:

```
SELECT t1.location AS Locations, COUNT( t1.location ) AS Total, 
tab.Responses, tab.location AS tablocation
FROM  `trespondent_acme` WHERE q13 <> 'OPTION' t1
```

But the above gives a MySQL query error, I've also tried before the two groups at the end of the existing query but again, no joy.

**EDIT**: I can now see that I don't reference or link `tresults_acme` in my query above and as Q13 resides within this table, that's the first hurdle I have.

Any advice welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure from your description, but to me it sounds like you are only interested in adding to the count from the sub query if it was either starter, or completed but not with Q13 being 'option'.

If so:-

```
SELECT t1.location AS Locations, 
    COUNT( t1.location ) AS Total,
    tab.Responses, 
    tab.location AS tablocation
FROM  `trespondent_acme` t1
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT location, COUNT( location ) AS Responses
    FROM  `trespondent_acme` 
    WHERE completion_status = 'Started'
    OR (completion_status   = 'Complete'
    AND q13 != 'OPTION')
    GROUP BY location
)tab ON t1.location = tab.location
GROUP BY t1.location,
        tab.Responses, 
        tab.location AS tablocation
```

EDIT

As results in another table you need to join against it in the sub query and check the value in there. However, no idea what column(s) you need to use to join the tables together:-

```
SELECT t1.location AS Locations, 
    COUNT( t1.location ) AS Total,
    tab.Responses, 
    tab.location AS tablocation
FROM  `trespondent_acme` t1
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT a.location, COUNT( a.location ) AS Responses
    FROM  `trespondent_acme` a 
    INNER JOIN tresults_acme b
    ON a.common_column = b.common_column
    WHERE (a.completion_status = 'Started' AND b.q13 != 'OPTION')
OR (a.completion_status   = 'Complete'
AND b.q13 != 'OPTION')
    GROUP BY a.location
)tab ON t1.location = tab.location
GROUP BY t1.location,
        tab.Responses, 
        tab.location AS tablocation
```

Comment: You are correct, so anyone that is Started or Complete but not with Q13 being 'option'.  I've tried your code about but get the follow error: `Unknown column 'q13' in 'where clause'`

Comment: Can you put the full table descriptions up? You say q13 is in the results table, but give no other info on that table. But reading your description I took the results table to be trespondent_acme.

Comment: I think I can see my problem.  At no point do I join the results table - they are two different tables: tresults_acme and trespondent_acme - my query above actually only looks at `trespondent_acme` and Q13 resides in `tresults_acme ` - so, I can see where I'm going wrong - just now trying to get my head around how to achieve what I need.  Apols if my descriptions are not clear!

Comment: So, what I need to do is still the same `count from the sub query if it was either starter, or completed but not with Q13 being 'option'.` but with Q13 being in `tresults_acme`

Comment: What fields do you use to join *trespondent_acme* and *tresults_acme* ?

Comment: respondent_id - it's not quite working - still counting the people with Option....wonder if it is do to with the AND/OR situ?  Just tried changing back to using IN for the Inner Where statement but get the derived table sql error with that arroach.

Comment: Can you post the actual table declarations and a bit of test data please? then I have a chance of testing any solution.

Comment: Just edited your post (can you peer review) got it working  as you'll see I have changed the INNER where clauses, tested and working 100% - thank you Kickstart - if you can peer review - I can upvote and accept your response.  Many many thanks.